# function to use an array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a function that uses the upper and lower bound of an array and returns the number of elements. It is confusing because of the lack of experience I have with functions but nonetheless I have come up with this code below:

```
Function numelement(LBound(array1), UBound(array2)) as Integer
    numelement =  UBound(array1) - LBound(array2)
End Function
```

Is this code correct, I know its simple but thats what the purpose of this code is to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you realy want to have a function (you can do it easily without it), then try the code below:

```
Function numelement(array1 As Variant) As Long
    numelement = (UBound(array1) - LBound(array1)) + 1 '<-- since array iz zero based
End Function
```

`Sub` Code to test the Function:

```
Sub TestFunc()

Dim Arr As Variant
Arr = Array("Shai", "Rado", "Tel-Aviv")

MsgBox numelement(Arr)

End Sub
```

**Note**: instead of the function, you can use:

```
Dim array1 As Variant
array1 = Array("Shai", "Rado", "Tel-Aviv")

MsgBox "number of elements in array are " & UBound(array1 ) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function for this. Ubound +1 works nicely for the total number of elements, if you initalize array like this `Array()`. It is a built-it function in VBA, it works great:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim myArr   As Variant

    myArr = Array("A", "B", "C")

    Debug.Print LBound(myArr)
    Debug.Print UBound(myArr)

End Sub
```

Unless you decide to initialize an array like this:

```
   Dim arr(3 To 4)
   arr(3) = 1
   arr(4) = 2
```

Then you should use the following:

```
debug.print UBound(myArr)-LBound(myArr)+1
```

Comment: "Ubound +1 would always work for the total number of elements": Really? `Dim arr(3 To 4): arr(3) = 1: arr(4) = 2: MsgBox UBound(arr): MsgBox (UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1)`